# SQLite Database - Compare DateTime

Tags: sqlite

I am working on a SQLite Database which contains a column which stores value in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. Now I need to create a filter to select rows with filter as this datetime column.
Query:

```
Select * from tbl_locations where datetime >= '2013-09-11 00:00:00' and datetime <='2013-09-13 00:00:00'
```

Above query is returning null set despite containing values in this slot(which I verified using select statement without filter.)

Any suggestion how can i get the required data set?

Comment: I'm not well versed in SQLite, but I have a table in MySQL that uses a variable of `timestamp` type.  Is the variable that you are reading from a string, date, long, or something else?  Also could you do a `describe` on the table so we can see the field information?

Comment: @zero298: all comparisons are among strings containing datetime formats as yyyy-MM-dd. Column is of Text type.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this excerpt from the SQLite documentation will help you:

**1.2 Date and Time Datatype**

SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

- TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
- INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

The date and time functions that you can use in your SQL to build your query are documented at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tested this out in MySQL but hopefully it will work.  I had a table that used `timestamps`, and changed the column to be of type `text`.  Then I tried the following SQL query and got the same results that I normally would (besides trailing decimals)

```
SELECT  timestamp(stock_quote_timestamp) 
FROM    stock.stock_quote
WHERE   stock_quote_timestamp < timestamp('2013-10-07 11:05:30')#@high_date
AND     stock_quote_timestamp > timestamp('2013-10-03 14:09:03');#@low_date;
```

So basically, just convert your `text` statements to `timestamps` so that they compare correctly.  Oh, and you'll also need to state what else you're `SELECT`ing, or you could do a compound select statement: `SELECT *, timestamp(stock_quote_timestamp)...`

Comment: This is not SQLite! SQLite would use `date()` and your query is comparing raw `stock_quote_timestamp` instead of calculated one.